Is this piecewise defined function locally Lipschitz?
Let $f:\mathcal{R}^n\rightarrow \mathcal{R}$ be continuous. Let $K\subset \mathcal{R}^n$ be nonempty and compact. Suppose $f$ is defined as $f=f_1(x)$ $\forall x\in K$ and $f=f_2(x)$ $\forall x\notin K$. Suppose $f_1$ and $f_2$ are locally Lipschitz functions. Is $f$ locally Lipschitz? If so, where can I start in proving that? Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Remark: I can see it is differentiable almost everywhere but that is not enough to imply local Lipschitzness. How do I show it is locally Lipschitz on the boundary of $K$? Those are the key points, right?

Consider $n=1$, $K=\{0\}$, $f(x)=\sqrt{\lvert x\rvert}$ and $f_1,f_2$ the restrictions. If you don't like $K$ having empty interior, consider $K=[-1,1]$ and $f(x)=\sqrt{\max\{x^2-1,0\}}$.

Is $f_{1}(x)=\sqrt{|x|}$ Lipschitz on $(0,1]$  ?

@Sassatelli Giulio Like Medo, I also fail to see why $\sqrt{|x|}$  is Lipschitz on $(0,1]$.

@Sassatelli Giulio I am having difficulty seeing why $f_1$, $f_2$ restrictions are Lipschitz for both of the counter examples you provided. Could you please elaborate? Thank you so much for your help.

@curiosity Locally Lipschitz on $\Bbb R\setminus{0}$. And it's because for all $x\in\Bbb R\setminus{0}$ there is some $\varepsilon>0$ such that there is some $h$ such that, for all $y,z\in (x-\varepsilon, x+\varepsilon)\cap(\Bbb R\setminus{0})$, the inequality $\lvert\sqrt{\lvert y\rvert}-\sqrt{\lvert z\rvert}\rvert\le h\lvert y-z\rvert$ holds. You may take $\varepsilon_x=\frac{\lvert x\rvert}2$ and $h_x=\sup_{v\in (x-\varepsilon_x,x+\varepsilon_x)}\frac1{2\sqrt{\lvert v\rvert}}$.

@curiosity More of the same for my other example.

@Sassatelli Giulio Just to be sure, so the statement I was trying to prove is false and these are the counter examples, right?

@curiosity The way I read your statement, yes.

@Sassatelli Giulio The second counter example is not Lipschitz at $x=\pm 1$ if the domain is $R$, even though it is Lipschitz on the restrictions. Is the right? Please bear with my incessant questions. I just want to make sure I get this. Thank you so much again.

I agree that the statement is false for a general compact set $K$.

@SassatelliGiulio If I require that the extensions of $f_1$ and $f_2$ are locally Lipschitz on $\mathcal{R}^n$, would we be able to proof local Lipschitzness of $f$? Should I write it as a new question?
